# is there a way to color specific text in pandas column (not whole column only specific text)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

How to color a specific text a in pandas `df` ?

The following code colors the whole cell. I'm trying to color only a specific word in the column.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a DataFrame (sample data)
data = {
    'sentence': [
        'sample sentence.',
        'sample sentence 2',
        'tewxt text text',
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define a function to format specific text in blue
def highlight_specific_text(text):
    if 'sample' in text:
        return 'color: blue'
    else:
        return ''

# Apply the formatting function to the 'sentence' column
df_styled = df.style.applymap(highlight_specific_text, subset=['sentence'])

# Display the styled DataFrame
df_styled

# Export the DataFrame to an Excel file
df_styled.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False, engine='openpyxl', encoding='utf-8')
df_styled
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know  there's no native pandas way to color part of a text within a cell in a pandas dataframe in a Jupyter notebook. If

If you need this for a data analysis and if you will use it in a jupyter notebbok, a potential workaround is to generate HTML styled string in pandas and .

If you want to export this DataFrame with partial text coloring, it would be very complex.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

# Create a DataFrame (sample data)
data = {
    'sentence': [
        'sample sentence.',
        'sample sentence 2',
        'tewxt text text',
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define a function to color specific text in blue
def highlight_specific_text(text):
    text = text.replace('sample', '<span style="color: blue;">sample</span>')
    return text

# Apply the formatting function to the 'sentence' column
df['sentence'] = df['sentence'].apply(highlight_specific_text)

# Convert the DataFrame to HTML and then display it
display(HTML(df.to_html(escape=False)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloring text is more simple :
First make sure to run your code in a display environment like Jupyter notebook and note that this in not modifying permanently the data frame.

add **str(text)** to  the conditional function :

```
def highlight_specific_text(text):
    if 'sample' in str(text):
        return 'color: blue'
    else:
        return ''
```

Then apply the formatting function to the DataFrame

```
styled_df = df.style.applymap(highlight_specific_text)
```